# Find undeclared variables in MethodDeclaration Eclipse JDT

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

How can we find undeclared variables in eclipse's JDT MethodDeclaration body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are looking for *references* that cannot be resolved (because the intended variable has not been declared), right?

You should create your AST with `setResolveBindings(true)` and then search for `Name`s whose `resolveBinding()` is `null`. This will also find unresolved type references, where a `SimpleType` or `QualifiedType` contains a `Name` node. This can be detected by asking `name.getParent() instanceof Type`. If `true` then it's not a variable reference.